# Sharepoint: is it possible to use an event like "on text changed" and populate others fields getting data from a database ?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint

I've a Sharepoint page.

I would like that when user enter in a field an "Id" , the page query a database then populate others field on the same page... using an event like "on text change" or if it is more simple, after a button click.

Thanks

Comment: Is it the default edit page for the list? If yes, you could write some Javascript using a content editor web part to fetch the data and populate into the form.

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages, pick one (or neither) and stick with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery, and drop an event for changes on your ID text box, this will perform the query and then load the data:

```
$(document).ready({

    $("input[Title='ID']").change( function(){ 
        // your query and data feeding goes here
    });

});
```

An asynchronous function paired to the change() will provide you with a better and more responsive UI.